# Acronyms to use for Bayesian posterior predictive distribution estimators

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, estimators, mse

I am considering writing an article that discusses the Bayesian MMSE and MAP of the posterior predictive distribution. I was wondering if there are acronyms that have been used so that instead of always saying: "The MMSE of the posterior predictive distribution..." I might just say: "The MMSPE..." or "The MMSEP" or something.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not an acronym, but you could just call it the predicted value or prediction, since the MMSE is just the expected value. Mean response and predicted response are terms used in regression, if that helps.

Comment: Actually, that does help! I was previously considering multiple estimation methods, so it would have been hard to distinguish, but then decided to consider only the MMSE for simplicity. Thanks!